# Add array of items into kendo ui multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

please pardon my noobness, but I'm new to working with Telerik controls. I have seen many examples of this but they haven't been able to solve my problem. I have a Kendo UI multiselect widget which contains some items and a button which, on clicking, would fill the multiselect widget partially with some items. These items are obtained as JSON from a controller method (ASP.NET MVC). So, the button click actually fires an ajax request and on successfully firing up, it calls a javascript function to fill the multiselect widget up. As of now, the ajax gets fired successfully and the data that I want is coming back successfully, just that the multiselect is not displaying the values.

My javascript/AJAX methods:

```
    function addItems(items) {
    var values = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        values[i] = items[i].Item.ID; 
        // gets values back correctly
        console.log(values[i]);
    }
    // print values
    $('#items').data("kendoMultiSelect").value(['"' + values + '"']);


};

// success
$(document).on("click", "#add-items-button", function () {
    var myUrl = $('#MyURL').val();    
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl, // get URL from view
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            addItems(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

My multiselect widget is a partial view so:

```
    @using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
    .Name("items") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .DataTextField("Name")   
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["items"])
    .Placeholder("Add Items")
)
```

Am I missing something very obvious? Am I writing the data back in an incorrect format to the multiselect widget? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add items to the data source of the multiselect.

```
$('#items').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataSource.add( { ID: 1, Name: "Name" });
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/eseYidIt/1/edit

Comment: So I don't actually need to use .value to render the data, is it? And can you please provide me with a demo in jsFiddle which does this for an array of data (in for loop) rather than hardcode the ID and Name?

Comment: Oh, sorry that this question is already resolved, but can you please tell me how I could remove these items from the list once they have been set in the multiselect widget area? Is there an event I need to call?

Comment: I think this is worth another question with code samples etc.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to others

> ```
> var multiSelect = $('#mymultiSelect').data('kendoMultiSelect');
> var val = multiSelect.value().slice();
> $.merge(val, "anil.singh@hotmail.com");
> multiSelect.value(val);
> multiSelect.refresh();
> ```

OR

> $('#mymultiSelect').data("kendoMultiSelect").dataSource.add({Id:"EMP100XYZ",
>   EmailId: "ayz@gmail.com" });